# Setting a logon script on Windows 10 adds +15 mins to first logon

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, login

I have created a batch script to create new local users on a new Windows 10 machine. As part of this script, I assign a logon script to the new user using net user:

```
net user %usrnme% /scriptpath:TEST.bat
```

At this stage all the logon script (TEST.bat) does is print "Hello World" and pause until I press a key so that I can tell that it is running.

Unfortunately, doing it in this way means the first log in takes an absurd amount of time, usually +15 mins. The next time the user logs on it takes a minute or two. Trial and error have confirmed that the logon script is the problematic part of my new user script. Without assigning the logon script, it takes the standard 2/3 minutes for the new  user to log in.

Any ideas why this is happening and/or on how to resolve it?

Comment: It sounds like you have set login/startup scripts to run synchronously instead of async.  If you can see the script to interact with it (the pause) then it is in a sync context, which kills all the modern login optimizations (bunches of parallel and async processes) by making the login synchronous with blocking calls.  If you can't see/interact with the script and it has a pause command, then login can't complete because the script is hung (waiting for press any key) and sits around for a timeout.  You want to **not** see the script (async call) and have it auto-complete without human input.

Comment: I recommend echoing "Hello World" into a text file and replacing your pause with an exit - this way you will still have a confirmation that the script is running but it will not hangup the login process. If this doesn't help your situation let us know and we'll try to give you more specific information.